# Gradle error download al ejecutar ionic build android

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic

Tengo un error al tratar de compilar una apk de un nuevo proyecto, ya que al parecer el enlace que debe agregar los **daemons** y todo acerca del **gradle** parece estar errado.

A continuación pongo el error.

```
C:\Users\pedromiguel\aplicacionesIonic\sqliteTest>ionic build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\pedromiguel\aplicacionesIonic\sqliteTest\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Users\pedromiguel\aplicacionesIonic\sqliteTest


add to body class: platform-android

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\pedromiguel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101

Subproject Path: CordovaLib



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

#### Información del sistema

```
C:\Users\pedromiguel\aplicacionesIonic\sqliteTest>ionic info

Your system information:

 ordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.17
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v5.5.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

He intentado múltiples soluciones que encontré en una pregunta, la cual pondré el link a continuación:

[enlace pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874564/ionic-build-android-error-when-download-gradle)

Comment: Actualizaste tu sdk a la ultima version de api?

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimienta acabo de ver que es en ionic :P

Comment: @Elenasys si tienes razon, jejeje :D

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a que el "heap size" llego a su limite.

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough
>   space for 2097152KB object heap

En internet encontraras varias opciones para cambiar el heap size, pero la única variable a cambiar es la relacionada al `MaxHeapSize`:

Desde el menú ve a `Help` > `Edit Custom VM Options` para abrir el archivo .exe.vmoptions

ahí puedes configurar

```
-Xms512m
```

Regularmente esta definida en 256m, así que puedes cambiar primeramente a 
512m y si eso no es suficiente a 1024m.

---

También puedes configurar desde Android Studio el "Max Heap Size" desde `File` > `Settings` > `Compiler` y en `Command-line Options`, agregar:

```
-XX:MaxHeapSize=1024m
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Es un problema de memoria para generar la maquina virtual

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for object heap
>
> Could not create the Java virtual machine.

Para solucionar dirigete a Setting desde File en el menú superior o pulsando 
ctrl + alt + s
Luego anda a: Build, Executions, Deployment -> Compiler.
E ingresa la siguiente linea en Additional build process VM options:

```
-XX:MaxHeapSize=512m
```

Vídeo respuesta: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVxm-ZH9wXA)

EDITO
acá hay varias soluciones: [soluciones](https://translate.google.cl/translate?sl=en&tl=es&js=y&prev=_t&hl=es-419&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F20307923%2Ferror-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-ob&edit-text=&act=url)

Comment: Ya pruebo, y te digo que tal

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales te ha funcionado? si es así, espero dejes marcada como respuesta correcta para futuros usuarios con el mismo problema. Saludos

Comment: Nada, la version de android studio que tengo no tiene esa interfaz para configurar, tengo la ultima, la 2.2.3, de igual forma, hare lo que hace la persona en el video en el archivo a ver si con eso solo sirve

Comment: configuralo directamente desde el archivo propierties

Comment: Si eso hago, y ya mismo pongo a compilar, disculpa, esta ruta si esta bien que la deje asi **http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip**

Comment: voy a eliminar la carpeta **.gradle**, y a probar de nuevo, por que ya esta cansando un poco

Comment: Un par de consultas, he leído que este problema es causado en win7 tras una actualización... usas win7? has reinstalado el jdk?

Comment: Tengo windows 10, tenia windows 7, pero actualice a 10, alli arriba, esta la información de mi pc, removi android para volverlo a agregar, que alli tambien sale un problema, si sale te lo muestro. que debido a eso es que no puedo compilar.

Comment: En ese caso asegurate de que tu "variable de entorno" 
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
Sea correcta.
probablemente sea necesario reinstalar el jdk

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50398/discussion-between-pedro-miguel-pimienta-morales-and-maguz).

Comment: aqui te dejo, un enlace, que es un **pastebin** del error que aparece al tratar de agregar android a un proyecto ionic [enlace del error](http://pastebin.com/A8qRGjZS)

Comment: aqui esta la imagen de a ruta, esta correcta [ruta del java](http://imgur.com/a/2bUSC)

Comment: existe esa ruta en tu disco?

Comment: claro aqui esta **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101**, pero no sabia que habia una actualizacion en el equipo, que es esta, **C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111**

Comment: amigo, creo que me va tocar reinstalar muchas cosas, estoy que formateo por muchas razones mas, creo que llego el momento.

Comment: ese debe ser el error, corrige el JAVA_HOME del ambiente. Es necesario reiniciar PC

Comment: bueno ya lo hago cualquier cosa, te respondo, espero no tener que pasar por el formateo.